# Expression « Sauf pour Capitaine Crochet ! »

Tags: expressions

J'aimerais connaitre le sens de l'expression « Sauf pour Capitaine Crochet! », si ça existe. Je l'ai entendu de la part de mon boss (sachant que la discussion n'a aucun lien avec Peter Pan).

Comment: Il y a plusieurs façon de rattacher une réflexion à un personnage imaginaire, quel est le contexte de cette référence patronale ?

Comment: Je lui ai dit simplement qu'on peut utiliser "on the other hand" sans mentionner avant "on the one hand" (pour une rédaction en anglais).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Un jeu de mot parce que le capitaine Crochet n'a qu'une main (hand).

Comment: Excellent! et moi qui a cru que c'est une expression que je ne connais pas.